# Shared Document Library URL

Tags: 2010, document-library

I was messing with SP's library forms (I think) a while back. Gave up eventually, because that wasn't really what I wanted. I did manage to break something, somewhere, though. Namely, the links to the default **Shared Documents Library** point to my `/SitePages/Custom.aspx` page.

For example, `Site Actions > All site content > Document Libraries > Shared Documents` links to `Custom.aspx`.

The library works fine and is available on its original URL, `/Shared Documents`, but the problem is that SP still links it to the custom page, which is not what I intend, and I can't remember what I did to change that.

Comment: http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2009/05/15/how-to-change-the-default-editform-newform-and-dispform/

Comment: thanks, @RobertLindgren but the I went for solution was simpler and required no coding.

Comment: I don't know about codig, but I agree Nadeem's solution was simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have changed the Default View of the Library. Go to Library Settings. Scroll Down and you will see a section named Views. Click on All Documents view. Check the option "Make this the Default View".

Comment: Yes, this was it! The library had no default view. I suppose I did set my custom page to be the default view, but I had deleted it eventually, so none of the existing views in the **Library Settings > Views** section were ticked. Thank you!